# Does the error "Value binding expects to be bound to a type of NSString" matter?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, cocoa-bindings

My app is a typical beginning Bindings example with a Stepper and a TextField.  The error occurs in the Bindings Inspector.  If you enlarge the image below and look at where the cursor is pointing, there is a popup with the error message.

[image]

The count property is of type `NSNumber*`.  And the TextField that is selected in IB apparently requires an `NSString*` value for its binding.  I read somewhere that the Cocoa Bindings apparatus can convert between types, and indeed I can Run my program without error.  So what is the error in the Bindings Inspector trying to tell me?

Should I change the type of count to NSString* instead?  That gets rid of the error in the Bindings Inspector, but a @property named `count` really shouldn't be of type NString*.

Answer (score 1):

Add a numberformatter to the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Type cast the property NSNumber to NSString or keep it as NSString object. Because **NSTextfield basically holds only NSString value**.

In that Model Key path, You should give NSString object's name.